Gitlab Unit Test report from console log
I am running some tests using console in a Gitlab pipeline. I am just printing the console output currently. However, I need to convert this output of console to Junit XML and publish this as an artefact for this to show up under tests on the pipeline. How do I do this? Is there any tool I can use for the same.
